# How to create insert into table where part of data is from one table and rest is filled

Tags: php, mysql

I have table messages where I am trying to create new messages to users. Algorythm looks like:

1) Get all user e-mails (they act as user id and is primary key in table user)

2) For each e-mail insert message (same to all), flag is read (false) and time (NOW())

How to do this? I wrote next, but I am sure that such line is wrong.

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`email`, `message`,`isread`,`createdat`) SELECT DISTINCT `email` FROM `users`, ?, false, NOW()
```

P.S. I am doing this via PHP, so ? will be message text.
For messages primary key is id that is AUTO_INCREMENT. Database: MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your literal value to the select clause as shown below.

Take a look at this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe8ee/1)

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`email`, `message`,`isread`,`createdat`) 
SELECT DISTINCT `email`, '?', false, NOW() 
FROM `users`
```

And the samething, but in PHP

```
<?php

  $myMessage ="...";

  $sql = sprintf("
                  INSERT INTO `messages` (`email`, `message`,`isread`,`createdat`) 
                  SELECT DISTINCT `email`, '%s', false, NOW() 
                  FROM `users`", 
                  $myMessage);
```

Comment: That's elegant. Never thought of it)

Comment: I would be worried about properly escaping characters in the message.

Comment: Without know which mysql library is being used, it is difficult to use the proper escape function.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql try this one

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`email`, `message`,`isread`,`createdat`)
 SELECT DISTINCT `email`,'Message' AS `message` ,0 AS `isread` ,NOW() AS `createdat`
 FROM `users`
```